# Is there a way to store a Swift closure in UserDefaults?

Tags: swift

After much research, I did not find a question about it. Is it possible to store a block closure in UserDefaults?

Comment: Why do you even want that kind of thing?

Comment: No - question, why? `UserDefault`'s a type of "data store", a closure is an "executable" element

Comment: This is an XY problem. Please [edit] your question and explain what problem you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per apple developer documentation [UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults)

> A default object must be a property list—that is, an instance of (or
>   for collections, a combination of instances of) NSData, NSString,
>   NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any
>   other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an
>   instance of NSData.